# Error while creating shortcut button C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to have a button that once you press it, it will create a shortcut.

Any time I press the button I am getting an error

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred

Additional information: Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))

Can anyone see why this is happening?

```
public static void CreateShortcut(string shortcutName)
    {
        WshShell wsh = new WshShell();
        string fileName = savDir + "\\" + ProductName + ".ink";

        IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)wsh.CreateShortcut(fileName);
        shortcut.Targetpath = Application.ExecutablePath;
        shortcut.Save();

    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
       CreateShortcut("folder");
    }
```

Comment: What UI technology are you using? Winforms? Please [edit] your question and add the appropriate tag. Also, not sure why you pass `shortcutName` as an argument and then not use it...

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `CreateShortcut` looks wrong:

```
CreateShortcut("folder");
```

should be (no quotes):

```
CreateShortcut(folder);
```

Comment: That sounds like it. Give it a try.

Comment: Nope this isn't it. It throws the error at             
IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)wsh.CreateShortcut(fileName);

Comment: @Webtest - The path to your file is not going to be correct, so technically it would throw at the line you specify. For example, your path is going to be `"folder\Blah.ink"` if `ProductName` is set to `"Blah"`.

Answer (score 0):

I also agree that you would want to change

```
"folder" -> folder
```

However, I got the same exception.  I think the issue is your extension.  Try:

```
".lnk" instead of ".ink"
```